# Search function through text in my page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, search

I am attempting to create a search bar for looking through text on my website without using external code (such as google's custom search engine).
I have been searching this for a while and without using php it doesn't seem like there is a good solution.
I have so far found this fiddle, but don't entirely understand how it works as I am new to js http://jsfiddle.net/pdgucocw/ (code from jsfiddle copied here:

```
function contains(text_one, text_two) {
    return text_one.toLowerCase().indexOf(text_two.toLowerCase()) != -1;
}

$("#searchText").keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val();
    $("ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).toggle(contains($(this).text(), searchText));
    });
});
```

right now I have this:

```
<p id="q">
    Some text, which is a lot of text, text text.
</p>
<p id="searchthru">
  Lots of text
</p>
<form>
    <input name="search" >
        <button type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which is, as you can see, just HTML.
I know this question is rather broad right now, so I'll try to specify what i'm attempting to do with it.
I have a landing page on the website, and then another page with quite a bit of text on it. The text page is well kept with aptly named headers and id's and so forth. I want a search bar on the text page (or even the landing page, but unless php is the only solution I would like to stay away from it).
Then, when someone puts something in the search bar, it can either search through the text in the headers and present the match, or search through all the text and then present the header text as the "options" for which to jump to in the search.

edit: This is to say to do whichever is more feasible/better user experience. I don't want the search bar to do both simultaneously, that makes little sense in my application.

For example, they type in "Water Parks" and they will be presented with options such as "Water Parks" "Parks" "Amusement Parks" "Theme Parks" etc. Then when they click their option, they will be brought to the correct section. If they type in "water" then the search bar will only bring up "Water Parks" assuming that the word 'water' is used multiple times but only in the Water Parks section.

I would very much appreciate it if someone would explain (as if to a 5 year old who is really good at understanding syntax but doesn't know what the functions do) the javascript code as they write it.

Eventually I would like to split up the text into many pages and I think that I would have to use php for that (from what I've read so far) but I would *REALLY* prefer a pure js solution. If this is impossible or otherwise just a bad idea, feel free to teach me php. Thank you so much.

Comment: The jsfiddle is pretty starightforward, it is searching just the text, but its hard to search text on all the pages and its time consuming. So Basically you want to build your own search engine.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to start out with just a search through one page of text and then jump down. If you could explain the jsfiddle that would be helpful.

Comment: Keep it offline, its too broad bsaraswat45@gmail.com

Comment: There are two javascript search engines that can do this (run offline): Lunrjs and search-index. I contribute to search-index and I'll see if I manage to put together an answer. Is it static html?

Comment: @EspenKlem it is static (for now and the near future). The search-index works a lot like the jsfiddle I put up, and I was wondering if I could change the functionality to bring the user to an anchor on the page (or even on a different page). If making it appear is the only thing though that would still be useful ! Thank you !

Comment: Sorry for late answer Quibble! Both Lunrjs and search-index will do that for you. Normally you would have a field for the url in each document indexed. It's there to build (in a template) the search result so you can click on it and get to the right page/place. Instead of a url, you just put the same content as in the anchor. Don't have time to create an example-app just now =/